# How to return regex match subset (perhaps via replacement patterns, but without replacing)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

Consider the following:

```
var string = 'http://awesome-site.com/page/#s-in=ascending'
var regex  = /(s-in=)([\w.-]+)/g


var match  = string.match(regex)
console.log(match) 
// this returns: s-in=ascending

// Using replacement patterns, it's possibl to select 
// a subset of the string selected via the regex

var subset = '$1' + 'new-string'
var match = string.replace(regex, subset)
cosnole.log(match)
// this returns: s-in=new-string
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return the string after the equals sign via regex (ideally the one in the example above, because the original string, a URL, is potentially quite complex).

**Question:**

How to return a subset of the regex-matched string, e.g.: the part after the `=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `exec` method and get the captured groups like this:

```js
var re = /(s-in=)([\w.-]+)/g; 
var str = 'http://awesome-site.com/page/#s-in=ascending';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    alert(m[2]);
}
```

Here, `m[2]` will hold the value `ascending` (the contents of the 2nd capturing group).

Note that if you are matching literal text, you do not have to capture it (here, `s-in=`). Adding unnecessary capture groups means unnecessary overhead. So, we'd better use `/s-in=([\w.-]+)/g` regex and refer to the text after `=` with `m[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the note about not needing to capture the first group and the suggested improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use exec, it will return an array containing all the captured groups and the full match.

```
var string = 'http://awesome-site.com/page/#s-in=ascending'
var regex  = /(s-in=)([\w.-]+)/g
regex.exec(string); //returns: ["s-in=ascending", "s-in=", "ascending"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// below line will create the new object of  RegExp constructor.

var (variable name) = new RegExp('Your Regular expression'),
  
    // now create another variable to hold the substring that will match 
    // for that (created Object)'s method called ".exec()" use by passing "string you want to match" as a parameter.

    (sub string variable name) = (variable name).exec('string that you want to match');
```

For Example

```js
var temp = new RegExp('/(s-in=)([\w.-]+)/g'),
              substring = temp.exec('http://awesome-site.com/page/#s-in=ascending');
```